# The sequence $(-1)^{n}(1+n^{-1})$ Converges or Diverges?

Tags: convergence-divergence

> The sequence $(-1)^{n}(1+n^{-1})$ :
>
> a)Converges to $1$.
>
> b)Converges to $-1$.
>
> c)Converges to $1$ and $-1$
>
> d)Converges to neither $1$ or $-1$.

The sequence looks like:

$$-1-\frac{1}{1}+1+\frac{1}{2}-1-\frac{1}{3}+1+\frac{1}{4}....$$

$$\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}..$$

$$\Rightarrow - ln(1+1)$$

$$\Rightarrow - ln2$$

Therefore, The series Converges to $-ln2$ and hence (d)Converges to neither $1$ or $-1$..

Is this correct?
And is there a better way to solve this which i am missing?

Comment: Hint. By setting $u_n=(-1)^{n}(1+n^{-1})$, what is $u_{2n}$? what is $u_{2n+1}$? Observe we are dealing with a **sequence** *not* a **series** ...

Comment: It's nonsense. The sequence is $-2, \frac{3}{2}, ..$. They don't get added up. And even if they did you can't just cancel out the $\pm 1$ as you did.

Comment: Oh, made a huge mistake adding them up, but even of i could, why couldn't i cancel $\pm 1$ ?

Comment: So , will the answer be c)?

Comment: your third point -  coverges to 1 and -1 - does not make sense.  If a sequence converges its limit is well defined (unique)

Comment: since $1+\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the sequence $(-1)^n(1+\frac{1}{n})$ behaves like $(-1)^n$, which diverges by oscillating between $-1$ and $1$...